# How to install different versions of r, e.g. r 4.1.2 in a conda environment?

Tags: python, r, anaconda, conda

I want to be able to install higher versions of R in my conda environment. In particular r 4.1.2. I have also installed Mamba fyi.

Currently r-base has:

```
conda activate main
conda search r-base

Name                       Version           
r-base                         3.2.4              
r-base                         3.3.0              
r-base                         3.3.1              
r-base                         3.3.2              
r-base                         3.4.1              
r-base                         3.4.2      
r-base                         3.4.3               
r-base                         3.4.3      
r-base                         3.5.1      
r-base                         3.5.3      
r-base                         3.6.0     
r-base                         3.6.1      
r-base                         3.6.1
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could specify the version directly:

`mamba install -c conda-forge r-base=4.1.2`

or

`conda install -c conda-forge r-base=4.1.2`

On  Jul 25, 2022 the highest available in `conda-forge` was  4.1.3 while in `pkgs/r` 4.2.0 was the highest version available.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate ! I had tried it with conda install it state such package does not exist as r-base maxed out at version r-base 3.6.1, shown above.
But I just managed to install it with Mamba thanks to your mamba command which is surpirsing as it rbase latest version seems to be 3.6

Comment: Something is not configured correctly at your end since I am able to run these commands and install the mentioned versions. Did you try in a fresh env? `search` states the highest versions I mentioned in the last sentence. https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/r-base

Comment: I think I had to restart my computer and it started working much better. Mate can I ask for an upvote for my question ;) as I am stuck on 11 points and need to get to 15 to be able to upvote answers or questions

Comment: it is a bit frowned upon to ask for votes, But! You should be able to 'accept' the answer. the checkmark under the voting of the answer. That would also give you some points.